# Kafka Connect FileStreamSink connector removes quotation marks and changes colon to equal sign for JSON message

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

## Summary

When I stream this with the console producer

```
{"id":1337,"status":"example_topic_1 success"}
```

I get this in from my filestream consumer

#### /data/example_topic_1.txt

```
{id=1337, status=example_topic_1 success}
```

This is a major problem for me, because the original JSON message cannot be recovered without making assumptions about where the quotes used to be. How can I output the messages to a file, while preserving the quotation marks?

## Details

1. First, I start my file sink connector.

   ```
   # sh bin/connect-standalone.sh \
   >   config/worker.properties \
   >   config/connect-file-sink-example_topic_1.properties
   ```
2. Second, I start console consumer (also built in to Kafka) so that I have easy visual confirmation that the messages are coming through correctly.

   ```
   # sh bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh \
   >   --bootstrap-server kafka_broker:9092 \
   >   --topic example_topic_1
   ```
3. Finally, I start a console producer for sending messages, and I enter a message.

   ```
   # sh bin/kafka-console-producer.sh \
   >   --broker-list kafka_broker:9092 \
   >   --topic example_topic_1
   ```

   From the console consumer, the message pops out correctly, with quotes.

   ```
   {"id":1337,"status":"example_topic_1 success"}
   ```

   But I get this from my the FileStreamSink consumer:

   #### /data/example_topic_1.txt

   ```
   {id=1337, status=example_topic_1 success}
   ```

## My Configuration

#### config/worker.properties

```
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/example.offsets

bootstrap.servers=kafka_broker:9092
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

#### config/connect-file-sink-example_topic_1.properties

```
name=file-sink-example_topic_1
connector.class=FileStreamSink
tasks.max=1
file=/data/example_topic_1.txt
topics=example_topic_1
```

Comment: Use StringConverter, not JsonConverter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're not actually wanting to parse the JSON data, but just pass it straight through as a lump of text, you need to use the StringConverter:

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
```

This article explains more about the nuances of converters: [https://rmoff.net/2019/05/08/when-a-kafka-connect-converter-is-not-a-*converter*/](https://rmoff.net/2019/05/08/when-a-kafka-connect-converter-is-not-a-_converter_/). This shows an example of what you're trying to do, although uses `kafkacat` in place of the console producer/consumer.

Comment: I've got a solution (above) that appears to work with the JsonConverter

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question when I was trying to solve a similar issue, and while it is old, I thought to post my answer:

My solution involves creating my own implementation of a `org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkTask`. In the `Sink`, where the Collection of `org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkRecord` is handled, I convert the `Map` (that the `JsonConverter` is outputting) using a jackson `ObjectMapper`:

So the connect-standalone.properties contains this:

```
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
```

Then in my class that extends SinkTask:

```
for (SinkRecord record : records) {
    Object recordValue = record.value();

    if (recordValue instanceof Map) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            recordValue = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(recordValue);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

This means in your example:

```
{"id":1337,"status":"example_topic_1 success"}
```

is reformatted accordingly as a valid json string - and this means that you can still use the JsonConverter which means you can still process the JSON in the transforms. I am doing this using a `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Value` to extract a section of the json as the value.